# Irreversible process with $dS=0$ (isolated system)

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility

Is there an irreversible process, where the entropy of the isolated system does not change?

Comment: I am assuming that you actually mean *isolated* (no exchange of matter and energy) instead of *closed* (no exchange of matter).

Comment: Yes, I do! Changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. An irreversible process is, by definition, one in which entropy increases.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to show it only using the (definition (?)) that a process is reversible iff its reversed process is also an valid one.

Answer (score -1):

2nd principle says that for a given system $dS = \delta S_e + \delta S_c$. Therefore if $dS = 0$ it is still possible to have $\delta S_c > 0$ (i.e. an irrevesible transformation) if $S_e = \frac{Q}{T_{ext}} < 0$.

For example, the Joule-Thompson expansion is an isentropic transformation though irreversible.

What is always positive when we think about entropy is the entropy created $S_c$, not the difference of total enthalpy of your system, which can exchange entropy with other systems (if not a closed system).

Comment: Thanks, but I am considering an closed system S_e = 0 and it seems that my problem stems from the definition of reversibility.